# Testing Conditions in For Loops

Tags: formatting, syntax

I am attempting to create a set of coefficients that satisfy a set of conditions using the Do function and If statements.

I did this successfully with a basic set of conditions:

```
Clear[x, y, z]
testCond = x y > 2
testCond2 = x y > 3
numList = List[1, 2, 3]
Do[
 Do[
  If[testCond,
   If[testCond2,
    Print[{x, y}]
    , End]
   , End]
  , {x, numList}
  ]
 , {y, numList}
 ]
```

But now I have a more complicated problem to attempt:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = r1 - b11 x - b12 y - u z;
g[x_, y_, z_] = r2 - b21 x - b22 y - u z;
h[x_, y_, z_] = -r3 + v x + v y;
sol = Solve[{f[x, y, z] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0, h[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, 
    y, z}];

xbar = x /. sol[[1]];
ybar = y /. sol[[1]];
zbar = z /. sol[[1]];

A = {{-b11 x, -b12 x, -u x}, {- b21 y, -b22 y, -u y}, {v z, v z, 0}};
charA = CharacteristicPolynomial[A, \[Lambda]]*-1;
coeList = CoefficientList[charA, \[Lambda]];
a0 = coeList[[4]];
a1 = coeList[[3]];
a2 = coeList[[2]];
a3 = Simplify[coeList[[1]]];
```

With conditions:

```
cond1 = r1/b11 < r2/b21;
cond2 = r1/b12 < r2/b22;
cond3 = a3 > 0;
cond4 = a1 a2 > a3;
cond5 = xbar > 0;
cond6 = ybar > 0;
cond7 = zbar > 0;
```

I attempted replicating what I did before:

```
numList = List[1, 2, 3];
Do[
 Do[
  Do[
   Do[
    Do[
     Do[
      Do[
       Do[
        Do[
         If[cond1,
          If[cond2,
           If[cond3,
            If[cond4,
             If[cond5,
              If[cond6,
               If[cond7,
                Print[{r1,r2,r3,b11,b12,b21,b22,u,v,a1,a2,a3}]
                , End]
               , End]
              , End]
             , End]
            , End]
           , End]
          , End]
         , {r1, numList}
         ]
        , {r2, numList}
        ]
       , {r3, numList}
       ]
      , {b11, numList}
      ]
     , {b12, numList}
     ]
    , {b21, numList}
    ]
   , {b22, numList}
   ]
  , {u, numList}
  ]
 , {v, numList}
 ]
```

But this doesn't actually output anything and so I'm stuck.

Also is there a cleaner method of attempting what I am right now? The code is long and doesn't look very good.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue; my initial conditions were set wrong.

```
A = {{-b11 x, -b12 x, -u x}, {- b21 y, -b22 y, -u y}, {v z, v z, 0}};
charA = CharacteristicPolynomial[A, \[Lambda]]*-1;
coeList = CoefficientList[charA, \[Lambda]];
a0 = coeList[[4]];
a1 = coeList[[3]] /. x -> xbar /. y -> ybar /. z -> zbar;
a2 = coeList[[2]] /. x -> xbar /. y -> ybar /. z -> zbar;
a3 = Simplify[coeList[[1]]] /. x -> xbar /. y -> ybar /. z -> zbar;
```

Otherwise the code works as intended.